# I need to change a PCI bus number for my NIC. (SETPCI)

Tags: pci, pcie, nic, lspci

after running lspci | grep net -i I have discovered that my NIC sits on the following bus:-
00:14.3 Network controller

how can I make it sit on any other bus ID ?

lets say for Ex. 00:01.0 instead of 00:14.3

is there any way to do that?!

Comment: If this is a desktop machine, you might be able to take a slot-based ethernet card and place it into another slot. Otherwise I don't know how you can change it, 'cause it has to do with a physical connection path. Why do you want/need to do this? Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Comment: oh thank you for your reply, no it's on a laptop. 

for "work" purposes. 

so there nothing to do with? (via setpci -s? maybe or any other configurations that related to setpci command??)

Comment: I don't know then. Sorry.